# visual studio 2012 c++ windows.h cannot be found

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012

My code is:

```
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

and I am running windows 8.1 and I have gone to my solution project, right click, properties and VC++ directories, and in include I have put Windows(C:)\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include
and the lib folder in the lib, but still I get the error message:

```
1   IntelliSense:cannot open source file "windows.h"d:\c++ project directx\Project1\Project1\main.cpp   1   1   Project1
```

and

```
2   IntelliSense: identifier "cout" is undefined    d:\c++ project directx\Project1\Project1\main.cpp   6   2   Project1
```

I have tried copy everything in Windows(C:)\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include and pasted it in the Local Disk(D:)\Program Files(x86)\VC\include
and included Local Disk(D:)\Program Files(x86)\VC\include in the include in VC++ directories, and at the same time, it doesn't even work for VS 2013 ether and it works in VS 2010 and Codeblocks. Please help!

I also get the error message:

Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory   d:\c++ project directx\project1\project1\main.cpp   1   1   Project1

when I debug

EDIT: I forgot to include iostream, but that didn't fix the windows.h problem

Comment: C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include doesn't contain windows.h (directly).

Comment: Arbitrarily copying your headers all over your hard disk is likely to make a bigger mess than you started with. Delete them and reinstall your IDE.

Comment: gonna try that, thanks!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit .. after each build;)

Comment: reinstalled Redistributable Packages and Vs 2012, but now I get the error that kernel32.lib cannot be found... and I reinstalled the windows 8.1 SDK.

Comment: just found the solution

Comment: VS 2012 will not use Windows SDK 8.1 by default. You have to manually use the [.props](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/18/visual-studio-2013-and-windows-8-1-sdk-rtm-are-now-available.aspx) solution for this combination. VS 2012 uses Windows SDK 8.0 by default which is included with VS 2012 Express for Windows Desktop and VS 2012 Pro+. If you have VS 2012 Express for Windows installed, it has a limited version of the Windows 8.0 SDK. VS 2013 is paired with Windows 8.1 SDK the same way VS 2012 was paired with the Windows 8.0 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Win32 project,for example:
File | New | Project | Template | Visual C++ | Win32 | Win32 Project (Not Win32 Console Application)

Comment: still dont work, but gonna try include the 8.0 instead of 8.1. but thanks for the advise.

Comment: If still dont work, I suggest you reinstall your VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my project was the problem, i checked the box for inherit from project defaults, and it fixed everything.